# Identify duplicates based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to identify duplicates in a db based on multiple columns from various tables. In the example below, 1&5 and 2&4 are duplicates - as all four columns have same values. How do I identify such records using a sql? I have used group by having count>1 when I had to identify duplicates based on a single column, but I am unsure how to identify them based on multiple columns. However, I see that when I do group by having count>1 based on all 4 columns, #3 and 6 are showing up, they are technically not duplicates per my requirement.

T1

```
ID | Col1 | Col2  
---| ---  | ---  
1  |   A  |  US  
2  |   B  |  FR  
3  |   C  |  AU  
4  |   B  |  FR  
5  |   A  |  US  
6  |   D  |  UK
```

T2

```
ID | Col1  
---| ---              
1  | Apple  
1  | Kiwi
2  | Pear  
3  | Banana 
3  | Banana 
4  | Pear  
5  | Apple
```

T3

```
ID | Col1     
---|  ---   
1  | Spinach  
1  | Beets
2  | Celery  
3  | Radish  
4  | Celery  
5  | Spinach  
6  | Celery
6  | Celery
```

My expected result would be:

```
1 A US Apple Spinach  
5 A US Apple Spinach  
2 B FR Pear  Celery  
4 B FR Pear  Celery
```

Comment: use `and condition` in group by having

Comment: Whats your expected result?

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your result set needs to include the ID column which is unique. So a straightforward GROUP BY ... HAVING won't cut it. This would work.

```
 with cte as
     ( select t1.id
              , t1.col1 as t1_col1 
              , t1.col2 as t1_col2 
              , t2.col1 as t2_col1 
              , t3.col1 as t3_col1 
       from t1
            join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
            join t3 on t1.id = t3.id
     )
 select cte.*
 from cte
 where (t1_col1, t1_col2, t2_col1, t3_col1) in 
      ( select t1_col1, t1_col2, t2_col1, t3_col1
        from cte 
        group by t1_col1, t1_col2, t2_col1, t3_col1 having count(*) > 1)
 /
```

The use of the sub-query factoring syntax is optional, but I find it useful to signal that the subquery is used more than one in the query.

---

> "I have encountered another scenario in the data, some of the IDs have same values in T2 and T3 and they are showing up as dups."

The duplicated IDs in the child tables cause Cartesian products in the joined subquery, which causes false positives in the main result set. Ideally you should be able to handle this by introducing additional filters on those tables to remove the unwanted rows. However, if the data quality is so poor that there are no valid rules you will have to fall back on `distinct`:

```
with cte as ( 
    select t1.id 
         , t1.col1 as t1_col1 
         , t1.col2 as t1_col2
          , t2.col1 as t2_col1
          , t3.col1 as t3_col1 
    from t1 
      join ( select distinct id, col1 from t2) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
      join ( select distinct id, col1 from t3) t3 on t1.id = t3.id
 ) ...
```

Comment: I have encountered another scenario in the data, some of the IDs have same values in T2 and T3 and they are showing up as dups.

Comment: I did so, please check ID 3 and 6. 3 and 6 are not dups per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all columns in the group by clause for which you want to find the duplicate and then write the count condition in having claus

```
select t1.id,t1.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3,t3.col4 from t1 join t2 on t1.id=t2.id join t3 on t3.id=t1.id where (t1.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3,t3.col4) in (
    select t1.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3,t3.col4
    from t1 join t2 on t1.id=t2.id join t3 on t3.id=t1.id
    group by t1.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3,t3.col4
    having count(*) >1  )
```

Comment: You have skipped the problem of joining multiple tables. This means your solution can't handle the additional wrinkles in the data.

Comment: @APC OP didnt not mention no.of tables at first instance, he changed it almost 2hrs later..Anyway I'll change it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

For your sample data, you can achieve this using `inner join-ing` all three tables and using just `group by tA.Col1 having count(tA.Col1)>1` in `where` clause sub-query as below to obtain your desired result.

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.Col1,
       t1.Col2,
       t2.Col1,
       t3.Col1
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID
WHERE t1.Col1 IN
    ( SELECT tA.Col1
     FROM table1 tA
     GROUP BY tA.Col1
     HAVING count(tA.Col1)>1)
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

**Result**

```
ID  Col1    Col2    Col1    Col1
-----------------------------------
1   A        US     Apple   Spinach
2   B        FR     Pear    Celery
4   B        FR     Pear    Celery
5   A        US     Apple   Spinach
```

You can check the demo [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e89904/60)

Hope this will help.

Comment: This solution only holds good if there's a firm dependency between `t1.col1` and `t1.col2`. I agree that applies to the posted sample test data but you're making an assumption that it applies in the real data

Comment: @APC: that's why first line of my answer is "For your sample data" :-)